# How to get value of property using typescript in angular 7

Tags: angular, algorithm, typescript, angular7

I want to take a value from my property, countOnProgress. I can get the value of countOnProgress when I subcribe, but outside subscribe countOnProgress return 0 so I cant use countOnProgress at progressLastYear. How to set value of countOnProgress with value from subcribe without return 0

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
import { Observable, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  alive = true;
  countOnProgress:number = 0;
  max: number = 200;
  value: number = 100;
  stacked: any[] = [];

  constructor(@Inject (DashboardService) private dashboardService: DashboardService){ 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    Observable.timer(0, 30000)
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.dashboardService.getCountProgress().subscribe(resp => {
        this.countOnProgress = resp.d;
        console.log(this.countOnProgress); //It found the data
      })
    });
    this.progressLastYear();
  }

  progressLastYear(): void{
    const types = ['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];
    const values = [this.countOnProgress];
    console.log(values);
    this.stacked = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.stacked.push({
        value: values[1],
        type: types[i],
        label: values[1]
      });
      console.log(this.stacked); //The datas: 0, succes, 0 (didnt get countOnProgress' value)
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code like below :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    Observable.timer(0, 30000)
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.dashboardService.getCountProgress().subscribe(resp => {
        this.countOnProgress = resp.d;
        console.log(this.countOnProgress); //It found the data
        this.progressLastYear();   // < -- move the function call here
       })
    });

  }
```

Why My code is not working ?

> JS is Asynchronous hence it doesn't wait for any I/O request to get
>   complete and keeps executing next lines of code.

In you code both `Observable.timer(0, 30000)` and `this.dashboardService.getCountProgress()` is asynchronous . Hence while executing JS will not wait for them to get complete and keep executing the next line of code. As a result the method call `this.progressLastYear()` got called before the completion of the service call . Hence You were not getting the value of `countOnProgress`.

Comment: I would just like to add an explanation as well. You see, in original version, progressLastYear() is called before subscribe() is called (which is called after 30s). 
That's why you need to move the method call in side subscribe.

Comment: @programoholic - I'd suggest you add a description to your answer for the benefit of future users. "Fixed" code without a description doesnt generally help people understand the problem.

Comment: @Tanmay_vijay JS is Asynchronous hence it doesn't wait for any I/O request to get complete and keeps executing next lines of code . :)